# Javascript slide down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to find something similar to the 'Table of Contents' drop down at the top located at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/ but for jQuery. It looks like that site uses the moo tools fx library. Does anyone know of an already existing plugin for jQuery that does the same thing or easy javascript code to accomplish the same sliding effect for that menu?

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I didn't think of that... I was even looking at the slideDown api the other day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there in the core; http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ . Just call that function in a link's onclick event and you should be good to go.

```
$('a.expand').click(function() {
  $('#toc').slideToggle(); // slide up if down, down if up.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that exact effect you'll just have to use the [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function built into jQuery.

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function(){
    $('#tableOfContents').slideToggle();
});
```

You'll need to wrap the table of contents in  and have a link/button/whatever width id="toggleButton" to activate it. Make sure the button is outside the table of contents  though!

Comment: Remember to use JS to hide the table of contents when the page loads rather than add `display:none` to it with CSS. This way if the user doesn't have JS the contents will be visable

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this links -

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/sliding-top-menu-with-jquery/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-top-panel-with-jquery/

You can even google out for more. There are many of them available.

Comment: these are nice alternatives. I like the fact that the top one will not move the page down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery .slideDown() and .slideUp methods.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

However something as big as that menu you probably want to call in on the fly with ajax with the callback function on slideDown.

Edit : The reason I recommend calling in the menu with AJAX is because of the usability/accessibility issue cause by having around 100 links off screen that a keyboard user can still tab through. It would take ages for a keyboard user to tab through all the off screen links to finally come to the "Table of Contents" link that activates the menu and then to shift tab back to the one he/she wants...terrible. The menu already does not work with JS off. (There is a link to the Table of Contents page below instead). Therefore calling the menu in with AJAX and giving the first link of the menu focus() is a much better solution.

Comment: You definitely don't want to have something as essential as your menu in an Ajax request! Google, but also users that don't have JS enabled won't be able to browse your site.

Comment: @Bjorn. I added a full explanation in the edit as to why in this case I would recommend the use of a dynamic menu, simply due to the amount of links.

Comment: I still don't agree; you should add appropriate tabindexes for those links, so more important ones will show up first, or place the menu further down in your HTML source. The menu _does_ work perfectly fine with no JS on, if you code it correctly (e.g. make it visible by default, hide it with js onload, so ppl without JS can actually see it).

Comment: @Bjorn Well we have to agree to disagree then. But there are many issues with having a menu that amount of links always on the page. Check out the main nav at the bottom of this page with JS on and off to better understand what I mean. http://www.channel4.com/news/

Comment: @Channel4: the links are already on the bottom of the page, and I personally think it is much worse if you can't access a page at all (for example, About the Programme) than if you have to try a little harder (i.e. skipping some links, which is not a problem if all if you have a decent screenreader, e.g. in Voiceover (OS X) try Control-Option-U) to get them.But this is a discussion that's not going to end, you think it's okay to hide lots of (important) links for non-js users, while I think it is not.

Comment: I think you mis-understood me, "About the Programme" is in the footer, not the site navigation and I never said anything about hiding important links. To be honest the real problem here is that if you have to show 100 links in your menu there is probably something wrong with your Information Architecture. Codeigniter would probably do better splitting the content up into several different landing pages. Eg. The top section links like Basic Info, Installation, Introduction, General Topics...etc are always on the page JS on or off. With JS on, all the child sections links can be brought in.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's mootools Fx.Slide. In jQuery you should use slideDown (http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)